# read_csv while skipping separator in certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a poorly formatted json file.
I am reading it using

```
mydata=pd.read_csv(afilename,header=0,usecols=[0,1,
                                                  4,5,
                                                  6,7,
                                                  8,9], 
                                         names=['ID', 'event',
                                                'a1','a2',
                                                'a3','a4',
                                                'a5','a6'])
```

Columns 1 and 0 are correctly read.
However, the following columns of my csv file might be malformed and contain stuff like

```
 '{Foo={"name":"bar",quantity:1.0,quantity_type:"baz"}, Fuu={"name":"barbar" '
```

which include the separator `','` which unfortunately is used a separator also elsewhere , and results in additional splits.

I do not know in advance how many `','` to expect, so everytime I change my `usecols/names` list to receive fragments of the column that get split due to extra separators, I get errors because the number of columns is not right.

Comment: Your sample neither looks like JSON nor CSV. Probably you have to write a custom parser for your custom format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are reading a JSON file you should use the [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) method instead of read_csv. This will work providing your JSON is properly formatted.

For example:

```
mydata = pd.read_json(afilename, orient='records')
```